# Laravel - How do I create a new request overwriting json()->all()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request, laravel-request

I'm developing an exporter, when I'm exporting data to an table I pass all the data trought post, inside a `records` parameter and the server discover if it needs to update or create a new row.

```
{
    "records" => "[{\"foo\":\"bar\"}]"
}
```

I get this `records` parameter and create another `Request` cause inside it can have child relationships, so I create another request to pass trought the validation.

```
$created_request = new NewRequest(
    [], // query
    ["foo" => "bar"], // request
    [] // attributes
);
```

The problem is, if I make a normal request, when I call `$created_request->all()` it will return me `["foo" => "bar"]`, correct, but if I make a json request, it will return me the old data `"records" => "[{\"foo\":\"bar\"}]"`

Basic, doing my research, I discovered that in a normal request, `$created_request->all()` will return `$created_request->query->all()` and `$created_request->request->all()`, on the other hand in a json request, `$created_request->all()` will return `$created_request->json()->all()` that always return the old data, how do I create a new request overwriting json()->all()

Comment: Did you tried to use `json_decode`?

Comment: @mare96 I use it when I create my new request, the problem is when I try to get the data from the new request